# Getting minimum with a default

Tags: ruby

In my `params` hash, I receive a value for `:limit`. I need to assign this value to a variable `limit`, but not exceed `50`, and if the value for `:limit` is not given, default to `50`.

First, I did this:

```
limit = [params[:limit], 50].min
```

This will make it maximum of `50`, but won't work: If nothing is given for `:limit`, then this will make `limit` `0`.

Next, I did this:

```
limit = [params[:limit] || 50, 50].min
```

This works, but I am wondering if this is efficient or if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: When the user does not pass anything for `:limit`, why does it become `0`?

Comment: `params[:limit]` will default to `nil` not `0`. However doing `to_i` on `nil` will return `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution it's quite easy to read but rather inefficient because you're creating an array and invoking the `min` method every time and it is an overkill.

A maybe less readable and more verbose but more easy on the machine approach could be:

```
if params[:limit] && params[:limit] < 50
  params[:limit] 
else
  50
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
limit = (params[:limit] && params[:limit] < 50) ? params[:limit] : 50
```